# ubuntu only boots from usb

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb

I very recently bought a new laptop. It came with windows 10 preinstalled so first thing I did was to install Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS via usb. I didn't opt for dual boot because I just wanted Ubuntu.

All things went well, except for booting.

It basically won't boot without the usb plugged in, and yet when it is plugged in I sometimes have to manually select the right boot in bios. It took a while before I found out that I could boot with the USB plugged in (only when I considered reinstalling).

I tried many different things I found via this and other forums. I found some similar topics/questions but they didn't help me in my case.

The last thing I found was trying boot-repair. It didn't help, here is the paste bin:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/whTRDkYhxP/

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [this reference](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-Hardware-General/Ubuntu-doesn-t-boot-unless-booted-from-USB/td-p/4546134) from Dell help?

Comment: Thanks 24601, it might. However, I'm struggling to find out which sdX i should use in the suggested solution.

Comment: Would it be sda as shown? check with the `disks` utility

Comment: it seems that sda is my USB, and my hard disk is called nvme0n1p2. So that would be nvme0n1p then?

Comment: Then it seems your boot device is still the USB not the nvme so the installation has not completed.

Comment: Great! But how do I proceed? I tried looking up 'completing unfinished installation USB' only to find issues related to installations that won't end. I'm sorry if the solution should have been obvious by now!

Comment: That might be worth an entirely new question... reference this one if you think it helps.

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu. Everything went well. Confirmed if I could restart without key: ok. Then I was asked to do updates (+400MB), I confirmed I wanted these updates and installed them. Restart: didn't work anymore. Again new hopes: "I found the problem", only to run into the same suggested solutions with unfortunately no alleviation. Only very weird: sometimes I can boot without key, then next time it doesn't work, then I need key, then I need to do weird things with boot manager... very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters the same problem, this is not a satisfactory answer but at least I can now use my computer:

- I reinstalled with an older version of Ubuntu (18.04) and everything works now.